# Only `Break` from innermost loop

Tags: programming

How could I `Break` from only the innermost loop in a

```
Do[stuff,{i1,i1min,i1max},{i2,i2min,i2max},...]
```

?

I get the desired behaviour if I use

```
Do[Do[...Do[stuff,{i1,i1min,i1max}],...]
```

but this hard to utilize because the number of loops in my program is not fixed, and therefore I normally create a `Table` the iterator specs with a function `myiterators[n]` where `n` is the number of loops, and use

```
Do[stuff,Evaluate[Sequence@@myiterators[n]]]
```

If `stuff` contains a `Break` here, it breaks all `n` loops... Instead of only generating the iterators, I could of course generate the full `Do[Do[...` structure using `Fold` or similar, but this does not seem like the best way.

EDIT AFTER LEONID'S ANSWER:

In my case, the function `myiterators` contains a call to a compiled function to evaluate the upper limits of the iterators. This precludes the use of `Evaluate[Sequence@@...]` since `Evaluate` forces the evaluation of the compiled function before the iterators aquire values in `mulitDo`. My solution was to use

```
ClearAll[multiDo2];
SyntaxInformation[
   multiDo2] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2, Infinity}}};
SetAttributes[multiDo2, HoldAll];
multiDo2[code_, {rest___, iter_}] := 
  multiDo2[Do[code, iter], {rest}];
multiDo2[code_, {}] := code;
```

and call it with

```
multiDo2[stuff,myiterators[n]]
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Use `Catch` & `Throw` instead of `Break`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen, how? `Catch[Do[If[j > 7, Throw[Null]]; 
  Print[{i, j}], {i, 9}, {j, i + 1, 10}]]` never reaches `i>1`...

Comment: See [`Catch` - Generalisations & Extensions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) for use of tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is a good case for a simple code generation. Here is one way to generate multiple `Do` in a macro-like fashion:

```
ClearAll[multiDo];
SyntaxInformation[multiDo] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2, Infinity}}};
SetAttributes[multiDo, HoldAll];
multiDo[code_,  rest___, iter_] := multiDo[Do[code, iter], rest];
multiDo[code_] := code;
```

Basically, `multiDo` is a new language construct. It constructs the nested `Do` code at run-time, without evaluating the body, and then evaluates the code, after it has been fully constructed. Notice that (as MichaelE2 pointed out in comments), the outer-most iterator in the multiple-iterator syntax becomes the inner-most one in the generated code.

Here is an example:

```
sum = 0;
multiDo[If[i > j, Break[], sum += i], {j, 10}, {i, 10}];
sum

(* 220 *)
```

In this case, similar result can be accomplished by

```
sum = 0;
Do[sum += i, {i, 10}, {j, i, 10}]
sum

(* 220 *)
```

but in general, one can't easily reduce the `multiDo` to a simple `Do` with multiple iterators.

Comment: Doesn't the normal order of iteration have the last iterator be the inside iterator?  E.g. `multiDo[code_, rest___, iter_] := (* same *)`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are right, nicely spotted! Will edit.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks for teaching me this way of doing it. I discovered that `Do[Catch[stuff;Throw[something]],i1spec,i2spec,...]` also seems to work. Do you know why? I don't understand how `Catch` somehow is outside only the innermost loop.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Indeed, it works, although it's not obvious at all that it should. I can well imagine an implementation of `Do[body, iter1, ..., itern]`, which would satisfy all the `Do` specs but where this won't work. So, unless I am missing something, this means relying on hidden deatails or an implementation (which one also often does, but which is generally considered not to be a great practice).

Comment: Another advantage of the method I proposed is that it won't be too hard to get it into `Compile`, if needed.