# Code to generate many Do-loops, where the $i$-th loop has upper bound given by $f(i$)

Tags: procedural-programming, iterators

How do I get Mathematica to run an arbitrary number of Do-loops, where the *i*-th loop it upper bound given by some function $f(i)$? I badly need help with this.

Let's denote the desired code by `Magic[k]`. Nested inside all the Do-loops will be some block of code depending on the loops variables, denoted by `Max`.

Here's an example of what I would like it to do.
`Magic[1]` would do the same thing as

```
Do[Max[k1], {k1, 1, f[1]}]
```

`Magic[2]` would do the same thing as

```
Do[Do[ Max[k1, k2] ,{k1, 1, f[1]],  {k2, 1, f[2]}]
```

`Magic[3]` would do the same thing as

```
Do[Do[Do[Max[k1, k2, k3], {k1, 1, f[1]]}], {k2, 1, f[2]}], {k3, 1, f[3]}]
```

and so on.

It would be nice to have an actual working example. let's assume my
`Max` is actually the `Max` function of Mathematica and that $f(i)=i^2$.

This might be bad coding practice but I find myself in dire need of it.

Comment: Related: [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/only-break-from-innermost-loop), in particular Leonid's answer.

Comment: @Marius - Any chance you understand Leonid's answer and are willing to elaborate here as an answer? I am having a hard time understanding his answer since his examples do not even use the code he suggested, and he manually types in the iterator variables and their bounds.

Answer (score 1):

One can use `MixedRadix` representation of a number for that matter. As an example consider a list `l` of length 3 containing `f[1], f[2], f[3]`. We can automatically build 3 respective loops each running from 0 to `f[i]-1` as follows

```
l = {2, 3, 5};
Do[Print[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[i, MixedRadix[l]], Length[l]]], {i, 0, Times @@ l - 1}]

(*
{0,0,0}
{0,0,1}    
{0,0,2}
{0,0,3}    
{0,0,4}    
{0,1,0}    
{0,1,1}    
{0,1,2}    
{0,1,3}    
{0,1,4}    
{0,2,0}    
{0,2,1}    
{0,2,2}    
{0,2,3}    
{0,2,4}    
{1,0,0}    
{1,0,1}    
{1,0,2}    
{1,0,3}    
{1,0,4}    
{1,1,0}    
{1,1,1}    
{1,1,2}    
{1,1,3}    
{1,1,4}    
{1,2,0}    
{1,2,1}    
{1,2,2}    
{1,2,3}    
{1,2,4}*)
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer `Tuples[]` for this: `Do[Print[v], {v, Tuples[Range[l] - 1]}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it is a shorter code, but it requires storage of all `Tuples`. I wanted to compute everything on fly.

Comment: @yarchik I'm not sure how to use your code. Would your code be able to do something like Do[ Do[ function(k1,k2), {k1,1,10-k2^2}], {k2,1,10}]?

Comment: @Camilo With this example you completely deviate from your original question. In the original post, your summation limits are *static*, i.e., known in advance. In particular, you suggested to call the upper limits as `f[i]`. Notice, `f[i]` depends only on the loop number `i`. I give a comprehensive solution to this problem. But now in your comment here you request that the upper limit also depends on the outer loop indices. Completely different story. Should be asked as a  different question.

Comment: @Camilo, I second what yarchik writes here. Please make a new question instead of editing this if you need the generalization that you request in the comments, and think carefully about the full scope of what you need the code to do.